# Absolute convergence of a series and parameters

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

I've been taught that if a series is absolutely convergent, then it is convergent.

I have a question, because my series has got a parameter within it. Let's call it b.

If a series is absolutely convergent for a parameter within an interval, I can conclude that in *that* interval it is also convergent (in my language, we call it "simply" convergent or convergent...does this nomenclature apply also for english? ...googled but found nothing...)

But my question is : could another  interval of the parameter exist for which the series is also "simply" convergent?

The series I'm talking is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) \frac{(b^n + 6^n)}{7^n}$$

I think that for $$|b|<7$$
the series is absolutely convergent (and also convergent).

Are there other interval in which the series is convergent?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can apply the limit comparison test to see that if your series converges, then the following series must converge, and vice versa.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}n\frac{b^n}{7^n}$$

since $\sin(1/n)\sim\frac1n$.  From here, we note that by the [Leibniz criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test), this series converges for $b=7$.

By the ratio test, it cannot converge for $|b|>7$.

By the integral test, it cannot converge for $b=-7$.

So the full set of solutions is $-7<b\le7$

Comment: Sorry, i mistyped my series ;) I updated the question, can you look at it please?

Comment: @f126ck Oh, well I'll see to that one then.

Comment: Thanks and again sorry for that sir.

Comment: @f126ck No problem, I'm done.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm accepting the answer. Let me see if I understood. The series is ABSOLUTELY convergent for |b|<7 and for Leibniz it is "simply" convergent  for |b|<7 AND 7 . So back to my question, It's true that  there CAN be an interval of the parameter (in this series it is only a point, b=7) in which the series is convergent but NOT ABSOLUTELY convergent

Comment: I mean, for b = 7 the series is convergent but NOT ABSOLUTELY convergent?

Comment: @f126ck Yes, that is clear.  Sorry for late reply